# Android detect which app handles intent

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, android-browser

In my application, I use an intent to open a browser. Is there any way I can find out which application the user uses to handle the intent? (A popup window appears when startActivity(intent) is called, and the user chooses which browser, or application, to use to handle the intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can find out which application the user uses to handle the intent?

Prior to Android 5.2, no, other than by implementing your own chooser UI using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`.

There is [a new version of `createChooser()` in API Level 22](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.content.IntentSender%29) that will notify you of what the user chose, by means of an `IntentSender` created from a `PendingIntent`.